# Calculate time difference between consecutive rows in pairs per group in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate the time spent per SeqID for each user. I have a dataframe like this.
However, the time is split between two actions for every user, `Action_A and Action_B.`
The total time per user, per seqID would be sum across all such pairs

For first user, it is `5 + 3 [(2019-12-10 10:00:00 - 2019-12-10 10:05:00) + (2019-12-10 10:20:00 - 2019-12-10 10:23:00)]`

So first user has ideally spent `8 mins` for SeqID 1 (and not `23 mins`).

Similarly user 2 has spent `1 + 5 = 6 mins`

How can I calculate this using pyspark?

```
data = [(("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:00:00", "Action_A")), 
        (("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:05:00", "Action_B")),
        (("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:20:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:23:00", "Action_B")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:10:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:11:00", "Action_B")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:30:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:35:00", "Action_B"))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "SeqID", "Timestamp", "Action"])
df.show()

+---+-----+-------------------+--------+
| ID|SeqID|          Timestamp|  Action|
+---+-----+-------------------+--------+
|ID1|   15|2019-12-10 10:00:00|Action_A|
|ID1|   15|2019-12-10 10:05:00|Action_B|
|ID1|   15|2019-12-10 10:20:00|Action_A|
|ID1|   15|2019-12-10 10:23:00|Action_B|
|ID2|   23|2019-12-10 11:10:00|Action_A|
|ID2|   23|2019-12-10 11:11:00|Action_B|
|ID2|   23|2019-12-10 11:30:00|Action_A|
|ID2|   23|2019-12-10 11:35:00|Action_B|
+---+-----+-------------------+--------+
```

Once I have the data for each pair, I can sum across the group (ID, SeqID)

Expected output (could be seconds also)

```
+---+-----+--------+
| ID|SeqID|Dur_Mins|
+---+-----+--------+
|ID1|   15|       8|
|ID2|   23|       6|
+---+-----+--------+
```

Comment: You can split the Action column into two new columns i.e., Action A and Action B and then take the difference between two values per Seq_ID and then do a group by aggregation.

Comment: you are suggesting pivot?

Comment: however, there are multiple values for same attribute names, pivot will not be able to handle it

Comment: For starters, you can get the min and max timestamp per ID/Action, and then calculate the difference per action. Then a simple sum rollup per ID will give the duration per ID.

Comment: I am not sure how min and max for each action will be helpful right

Comment: Totally true. Misread the data

Comment: BTW, can you explain "multiple values of the same attribute" from your comment above?

Comment: for ID1, SeqID 15, you have two values for each action. Hence when you will pivot, it will not be what we intend to. It would have worked, if we had 2 values only per ID and seqID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using [Higher-Order Functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) (Spark >=2.4):

```
transform_expr = "transform(ts_array, (x,i) -> (unix_timestamp(ts_array[i+1]) - unix_timestamp(x))/60 * ((i+1)%2))"

df.groupBy("ID", "SeqID").agg(array_sort(collect_list(col("Timestamp"))).alias("ts_array")) \
    .withColumn("transformed_ts_array", expr(transform_expr)) \
    .withColumn("Dur_Mins", expr("aggregate(transformed_ts_array, 0D, (acc, x) -> acc + coalesce(x, 0D))")) \
    .drop("transformed_ts_array", "ts_array") \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

**Steps:**

1. Collect all timestamps to array for each group `ID`, `SeqID` and sort them in ascending order
2. Apply a transform to the array with lambda function `(x, i) => Double`. Where `x` is the actual element and `i` its index. For each timestamp in the array, we calculate the diff with the next timestamp. And we multiply by `(i+1)%2` in order to have only the diff as pairs 2 per 2 (first with the second, third with the fourth, ...) as there are always 2 actions.
3. Finally, we aggregate the result array of transformation to sum all the elements.

Output:

```
+---+-----+--------+
|ID |SeqID|Dur_Mins|
+---+-----+--------+
|ID1|15   |8.0     |
|ID2|23   |6.0     |
+---+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible (might be complicated as well) way to do it with `flatMapValues` and `rdd`

Using your `data` variable

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "seq_id", "ts", "action"]). \
    withColumn('ts', func.col('ts').cast('timestamp'))

# func to calculate the duration | applied on each row
def getDur(groupedrows):
    """
    """

    res = []

    for row in groupedrows:
        if row.action == 'Action_A':
            frst_ts = row.ts
            dur = 0
        elif row.action == 'Action_B':
            dur = (row.ts - frst_ts).total_seconds()

        res.append([val for val in row] + [float(dur)])

    return res

# run the rules on the base df | row by row
# grouped on ID, SeqID - sorted on timestamp
dur_rdd = df.rdd. \
    groupBy(lambda k: (k.id, k.seq_id)). \
    flatMapValues(lambda r: getDur(sorted(r, key=lambda ok: ok.ts))). \
    values()

# specify final schema
dur_schema = df.schema. \
    add('dur', 'float')

# convert to DataFrame
dur_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(dur_rdd, dur_schema)

dur_sdf.orderBy('id', 'seq_id', 'ts').show()

+---+------+-------------------+--------+-----+
| id|seq_id|                 ts|  action|  dur|
+---+------+-------------------+--------+-----+
|ID1|    15|2019-12-10 10:00:00|Action_A|  0.0|
|ID1|    15|2019-12-10 10:05:00|Action_B|300.0|
|ID1|    15|2019-12-10 10:20:00|Action_A|  0.0|
|ID1|    15|2019-12-10 10:23:00|Action_B|180.0|
|ID2|    23|2019-12-10 11:10:00|Action_A|  0.0|
|ID2|    23|2019-12-10 11:11:00|Action_B| 60.0|
|ID2|    23|2019-12-10 11:30:00|Action_A|  0.0|
|ID2|    23|2019-12-10 11:35:00|Action_B|300.0|
+---+------+-------------------+--------+-----+

# Your required data
dur_sdf.groupBy('id', 'seq_id'). \
    agg((func.sum('dur') / func.lit(60)).alias('dur_mins')). \
    show()

+---+------+--------+
| id|seq_id|dur_mins|
+---+------+--------+
|ID1|    15|     8.0|
|ID2|    23|     6.0|
+---+------+--------+
```

This fits the data you've described, but check if it fits your all your cases.

Comment: In case [higher order functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) aren't available to you (spark < 2.4)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using Window Functions

```
spark = SparkSession.Builder().master("local[3]").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

data = [(("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:00:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:05:00", "Action_B")),
        (("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:20:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID1", 15, "2019-12-10 10:23:00", "Action_B")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:10:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:11:00", "Action_B")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:30:00", "Action_A")),
        (("ID2", 23, "2019-12-10 11:35:00", "Action_B"))]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "SeqID", "Timestamp", "Action"])

df.registerTempTable("tmpTbl")

df = spark.sql("select *, lead(Timestamp,1) over (partition by ID,SeqID order by Timestamp) Next_Timestamp from tmpTbl")

updated_df = df.filter("Action != 'Action_B'")

final_df = updated_df.withColumn("diff", (F.unix_timestamp('Next_Timestamp') - F.unix_timestamp('Timestamp'))/F.lit(60))

final_df.groupBy("ID","SeqID").agg(F.sum(F.col("diff")).alias("Duration")).show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxTig.png)